# Number of wrong answers

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In a certain test $a_i$  students gave wrong answers to at least i questions, where $i= 1,2,3......k$ No student gave more than k wrong answers. The total number of wrong answers is

I wasn't able to start solving this. I tried subtracting 2-1 for exactly 1 answer but I didn't understand what was happening. The solution provided uses the same logic from the below sum of Therefore, total number of wrong answers contributed by $2^{n−i} −2^{n−i−1}$ students who answered i questions wrong is $(2^{n−i}−2^{n−i−1})i$. I have no clue how this was derived.

There is a similar question on the site already but it is the other way around and doesn't resolve my doubt.
[To find number of questions when number of wrong answers is given](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1228286/to-find-number-of-questions-when-number-of-wrong-answers-is-given)

Comment: Did you mean to write $(2^{n - i} - 2^{n - i - 1})i$?  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig okay ill check it out thanks!

Comment: HINT: How many students gave precisely $i$ wrong answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The number who gave at least $k$ wrong answers is $a_k$.  Since no student gave more than $k$ wrong answers, the number who gave exactly $k$ wrong answers is $a_k$.
- The number who gave at least $k-1$ wrong answers is $a_{k-1}$.  Since $a_k$ students gave more than $k-1$ wrong answers, the number who gave exactly $k-1$ wrong answers is $a_{k-1}-a_k$.
- The number who gave at least $k-2$ wrong answers is $a_{k-2}$.  Since $a_{k-1}$ students gave more than $k-2$ wrong answers, the number who gave exactly $k-2$ wrong answers is $a_{k-2}-a_{k-1}$.
- $\cdots$
- The number who gave at least $1$ wrong answer is $a_{1}$.  Since $a_2$ students gave more than $1$ wrong answer, the number who gave exactly $1$ wrong answers is $a_1-a_2$.

So the total number of wrong answers is $$1(a_1-a_2)+2(a_2-a_3) +\cdots+(k-1)(a_{k-1}-a_k)+k(a_k)$$ $$=a_1 +a_2(2-1)+a_3(3-2)+\cdots+a_k(k-(k-1))$$ $$=a_1+a_2+a_3+...+ a_k$$ $$=\sum\limits_1^k a_n$$

Comment: I do not understand the second line. ak-1 is < ak. So the value come out on negative ? Could you please simplify it a little bit, or maybe just word it in a different way ? I tried this was ak=5 and ak-1= 4 but did not get it.

Comment: I got it. I was assumimg ak> ak-1 when the values would actually be converging. Thanks!